# Targeting URL content and displaying on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a client who's stuck using a widget based website and needs a custom built web app. We're hosting it off site. I need to pull product information from their main site to populate the off site page.

I wrote this to pull H1 content from their main site, this will serve as the link to the off site page.

```
<a href="#" id="specialURL">BUILD LEASE</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = $('h1').html();
  url = url.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()+'.html';


  console.log(url);
$('#specialURL').attr('href', 'http://joethemovie.com/' + url );



});
```

Now I need to turn the URL content back into an h1 on the off site page.

Also, if possible, does anyone know how I could store price information in the URL?

Such as http://example.com/mainSiteH1&price=12345

Then, same as the H1, display on the off site page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you're sticking in a url should be uri encoded. this will take care of spaces too so the regex isn't necessary..

```
$('#specialURL').attr('href', 'http://joethemovie.com/?h1=' + encodeURIComponent(url) +"&price=" + encodeURIComponent("about tree fiddy"));
```

Then you can get that junk from the url using the server (php's `$_GET` for example), or you can use the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to get those parameters with javascript..